# cadena vacia para getElementById(); en nav-tab de boostrap 5 personalizado

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap

Me encuentro utilizando un poco boostrap 5 para aprender mas de frontend pero tengo un problema a la hora de utilizar una nav-tab que yo mismo personalicé

```css
body {
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
    align-items: center !important;
    background-color: #1ed671f6;
}

.container__first{
    max-width: 200em;
    margin: 2% 25%;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 1em;
}

.menu-active {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #1ed671f6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container container__first rounded">
        <nav>
            <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-around mb-4 nav" role="tablist">
                <div class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <a href="#registro" id="nav-registro-tab" class="h4 fw-bold text-decoration-none text-dark" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#registro" role="tab" aria-controls="registro" aria-selected="true">Registro</a>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <a href="#login" id="nav-login-tab" class="h4 fw-bold text-decoration-none text-dark" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#login" role="tab" aria-controls="login" aria-selected="false">Login</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="tab-content">            
            <form id="registro" class="justify-content tab-pane fade show active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Registro">
            <div class="ml-3 mr-3 col-auto">
                    <label for="" class="form-label fw-bold text-decoration-none text-dark"> Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control" require>
                </div>
                <div class="ml-3 mr-3 col-auto">
                    <label for="" class="form-label fw-bold text-decoration-none text-dark">Contraseña</label>
                    <input type="password" name="" id="" class="form-control" require>
                
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-success">Registrar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <form id="login" class="justify-content tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Login">
                <div class="ml-3 mr-3 col-auto">
                    <label for="" class="form-label fw-bold text-decoration-none text-dark">Usuario / Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control" require>
                </div>
                <div class="ml-3 mr-3 col-auto">
                    <label for="" class="form-label fw-bold text-decoration-none text-dark">Contraseña</label>
                    <input type="password" name="" id="" class="form-control" require>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Mi problema está a la hora de hacer click en los elementos  el js de boostrap toma las primeras 2 veces ambos elementos y cuando quiero hacer click una tercera vez no funciona y en la consola empieza enviar el mensaje de "Cadena vacía pasada a getElementById()." cada vez que se le da click a los elementos .

Comment: Creo que va por otro lado los tiros, Cadena vacía pasada a getElementById(), javascript está buscando un ID, relacionado a un evento de tu menu? pero en tu css y html del menu no veo ningun ID definido id="", entiendo que tu menu necesita IDs para funcionar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para el sistema de **tabs** que estás usando, Bootstrap necesita que tanto el **tablist** como los **tab-item** sean un `<ul>` y `<li>` respectivamente. Al tenerlos como `<div>` provocabas el comportamiento extraño que nos muestras.

Lo de la cadena vacía que nos comentas se trata de un problema que no parece tener relación con el error en las tabs.

```css
body {
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
    align-items: center !important;
    background-color: #1ed671f6;
}

.container__first{
    max-width: 200em;
    margin: 2% 25%;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 1em;
}

.menu-active {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #1ed671f6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container container__first rounded">
        <nav>
            <ul class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-around mb-4 nav" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <a href="#registro" id="nav-registro-tab" class="h4 fw-bold text-decoration-none text-dark" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#registro" role="tab" aria-controls="registro" aria-selected="true">Registro</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <a href="#login" id="nav-login-tab" class="h4 fw-bold text-decoration-none text-dark" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#login" role="tab" aria-controls="login" aria-selected="false">Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="tab-content">            
            <form id="registro" class="justify-content tab-pane fade show active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Registro">
            <div class="ml-3 mr-3 col-auto">
                    <label for="" class="form-label fw-bold text-decoration-none text-dark"> Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control" require>
                </div>
                <div class="ml-3 mr-3 col-auto">
                    <label for="" class="form-label fw-bold text-decoration-none text-dark">Contraseña</label>
                    <input type="password" name="" id="" class="form-control" require>
                
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-success">Registrar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <form id="login" class="justify-content tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Login">
                <div class="ml-3 mr-3 col-auto">
                    <label for="" class="form-label fw-bold text-decoration-none text-dark">Usuario / Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control" require>
                </div>
                <div class="ml-3 mr-3 col-auto">
                    <label for="" class="form-label fw-bold text-decoration-none text-dark">Contraseña</label>
                    <input type="password" name="" id="" class="form-control" require>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```